# how to specify the locale when cordova build

Tags: cordova

When I use Xcode to build and export the ipa for a cordova project, there has a localization option I can choose with Chinese. When I turn to use cordova build -device to generate an ipa directly without Xcode. How can I specify the locale option from the command line

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the language in `platforms/ios/{appName}/{appName}-Info.plist`.

The key for the language is `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`, the value is `English` by default.

I'm not sure which value are allowed exactly. I tried it with `Dutch`, but I think `Chinese` is a valid value as well.

I've created a simple [Cordova hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/) to automate this task. Just use it as a `after_platform_add` hook for the ios platform.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const plist = require('plist');


module.exports = context => {
  const ConfigParser = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-common').ConfigParser;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let config = new ConfigParser(path.resolve(context.opts.projectRoot, 'config.xml'));
    let name = config.name();
    let plistPath = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms', 'ios', name, `${name}-Info.plist`);

    fs.readFile(plistPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      let infoPlist = plist.parse(data);
      infoPlist.CFBundleDevelopmentRegion = 'Chinese';
      fs.writeFile(plistPath, plist.build(infoPlist), err => {
        if (err) {
          return reject();
        }
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
};
```